# throw new Error('invalid schema,expected mongodb');

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gruntjs, mean-stack, nodemon

Getting Error: `invalid schema, expected mongodb` , while starting server using `nodeman`

```
C:\Users\NDLM\Documents\workspace\angular-drywall>nodemon app.js
[nodemon] 1.12.0
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
C:\Users\NDLM\Documents\workspace\angular-drywall\node_modules\mongodb\lib\url_parser.js:20
    throw new Error('invalid schema, expected mongodb');
    ^

Error: invalid schema, expected mongodb
    at module.exports (C:\Users\NDLM\Documents\workspace\angular-drywall\node_modules\mongodb\lib\url_parser.js:20:11)
    at connect (C:\Users\NDLM\Documents\workspace\angular-drywall\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:125:16)
    at Function.MongoClient.connect (C:\Users\NDLM\Documents\workspace\angular-drywall\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:109:3)
    at initWithUrl (C:\Users\NDLM\Documents\workspace\angular-drywall\node_modules\connect-mongo\lib\connect-mongo.js:185:19)
    at new MongoStore (C:\Users\NDLM\Documents\workspace\angular-drywall\node_modules\connect-mongo\lib\connect-mongo.js:241:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\NDLM\Documents\workspace\angular-drywall\app.js:54:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:573:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:584:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:507:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:470:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:462:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:609:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:598:3
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: share your code

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this code snippet from the `mongodb` `url_parser.js` file
Line 20 to be exact.

```
if(result.protocol != 'mongodb:') {
    throw new Error('invalid schema, expected mongodb');
}
```

This tells me that the uri connection string **IS NOT** using the required `mongodb://` prototcol
Change your uri connection string. And your Server should stop crashing.

Package example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb#connecting-to-mongodb